# PHP case switch print message

Tags: php

I am playing about with PHP, At the moment i am working with `case switch` functions. I want to create random number up to 100 and based on the random number output echo a message.

My php code:

```
$number = rand(1, $limit);



    switch($number){

        case "range1":
            if($number >=1 || $number <=25 ){
                print 'You win nothihg';
            }else{
                print 'Your Score is: '.$number;
            }
            break;
        case "range2":
            if($number >25 || $number <=50 ){
                print 'You win Small Prize';
            }else{
                print 'Your Score is: '.$number;
            }
            break;
        case "range3":
            if($number >50 || $number <=75 ){
                print 'You win Medium Prize';
            }else{
                print 'Your Score is: '.$number;
            }
            break;
        case "range4":
            if($number >75 || $number <=100){
                print 'You win Large Prize';
            }else{
                print 'Your Score is: '.$number;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if($number <=75) {
                print 'Keep tryintg untill you win Large';
            }
    }
```

The problem I am having that the messages do not get displayed.....I dont know where I am going wrong in here..?

Comment: Why are you comparing a random number with the string "range1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rand` function will return you a number between the limits you set as the 2 arguments, in this case, `1`, and the value of `$limit`

As you are not concatenating your `$number` variable with the word `range`, it is never returned as a value, please observe:

```
$number = rand(1,2);
//$number = 1 or 2

switch($number):
    //possible cases are case '1' and case '2'
endswitch;
```

If you wished to have `range` concatenated, then:

```
$number = 'range' . rand(1,$limit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have bad condition. Read manual about [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) it returns int values. 
Also read manual on [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) generally switch enters case block if case condition is true. In your case "range1".."range[n]" is always false with comparing to int number.

i would use something like this:

```
switch($number){
 case $number<=1:
  echo "less than one";
  break;
 case $number<=50:
  echo "less than 50";
  break;
 default:
//do something default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$number will not return your switch keyword 'range' but it will return an integer value!
Simply put your If-condition as case statement and print the price-size respectively

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a random number to the switch and expecting a string, you'll never be able to display any message, except if you put it in the default case.